# ASP.NET MVC4 HtmlHelper outputting extra unwanted markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

So basically, i'm seeing a ';' appearing out of nowhere. I have no idea where it comes from and no apparent source for it.

I have No javascript or css in this test site.

My Model: (Not that it matters)

```
public class RegisterAccountViewModel
    {        
        public long? Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AccountType { get; set; }
        public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    }
```

The View (Test.cshtml):

```
@model RegisterAccountViewModel
@{Layout = null;}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName"/>
    <br/>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new {placeholder = "Last Name" });
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterAccountViewModel model)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[image]

What gives?

To make sure it wasnt any problem in my part, i created a new mvc site using the default template and added a textbox; the result is the same as seen in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove semicolon `;` at the end of **LastName TextBoxFor**.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new {placeholder = "Last Name" }); //<-- remove this semicolon
```

**NOTE :-** In razor(MVC) syntax `;` is only required when you are writing some C# code inside `@{}`, there is no need of `;` at the end of html helper extension methods.

Comment: Lol :) now im ashamed i asked :)

Comment: happy to help you..;)

Answer (score 2):

You must remove ';' at the end line in your view:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new {placeholder = "Last Name" })`